# Sublime FTP/SFTP

Tags: ftp, sublimetext3, sftp

I am trying to connect to my cpanel server using sublime text 3. 
Server is added successfully. And remote path is also validated successfully.
But when try to Sync Remote->Local it is just not happening.

```
 {
// The tab key will cycle through the settings when first created
// Visit http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/settings for help

// sftp, ftp or ftps
"type": "ftp",

"save_before_upload": true,
"upload_on_save": true,
"sync_down_on_open": false,
"sync_skip_deletes": false,
"sync_same_age": true,
"confirm_downloads": false,
"confirm_sync": true,
"confirm_overwrite_newer": false,

"host": "XXXXXX",
"user": "XXXXX",
"password": "XXXXXXX",
"port": "21",

"remote_path": "XXXXXX",
"ignore_regexes": [
    "\\.sublime-(project|workspace)", "sftp-config(-alt\\d?)?\\.json",
    "sftp-settings\\.json", "/venv/", "\\.svn/", "\\.hg/", "\\.git/",
    "\\.bzr", "_darcs", "CVS", "\\.DS_Store", "Thumbs\\.db", "desktop\\.ini"
],
//"file_permissions": "664",
//"dir_permissions": "775",

//"extra_list_connections": 0,

"connect_timeout": 30,
//"keepalive": 120,
//"ftp_passive_mode": true,
//"ftp_obey_passive_host": false,
//"ssh_key_file": "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
//"sftp_flags": ["-F", "/path/to/ssh_config"],

//"preserve_modification_times": false,
//"remote_time_offset_in_hours": 0,
//"remote_encoding": "utf-8",
//"remote_locale": "C",
//"allow_config_upload": false,
}
```

And in the console I finally got this:
"Select via quick panel? No".

And the process got terminated by itself.

Comment: This is a bug with Sublime Text. If the window is not active when the initial sync is complete, it will default to "no".

see https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/sftp-quick-panel-shows-up-inconsistently/9777/5

Answer (score 2):

SFTP has some options for that to put on your sftp-config.json file at the root of your folder :

Set those values like this:

```
    "confirm_downloads":false,
    "confirm_sync":false,
    "confirm_overwrite_newer":true
```